# Javascript - How to validate basic input

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some code to do validations on a input data that comes from the frontend HTTP post payload. I want to make sure the data comes in the format I expect before inserting into the database...
I'm using just NodeJS and javascript...

I think my approach is pretty ugly. IS there any alternatives to this approach??

```js
const data = [{
  type: 'YY',
  model: 'Ford',
  year: 2000,
  class: 'Small Car'
}, {
  type: 'ZZ',
  model: 'Fiat',
  class: 'Small Car'
}];

console.log(data);

let isValid = true;

data.forEach(elem => {
  if (!elem.type || elem.type.length !== 2) isValid = false;
  if (!elem.model) isValid = false;
  if (!elem.year) isValid = false;
  if (!elem.class) isValid = false;
})

console.log(isValid);
```

Comment: If any of those 4 conditions is false you should return it rather then checking further. also you can filter out the data as well by `.filter()` method to exclude the invalid data. and also you can check all 4 conditions at once by `if([cond1, cond2, cond3, ...].includes(null))`

Comment: this works exactly like you want? & you just another approach..am i understanding that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If any of those four conditions is false you should return it rather then checking further iteration. also you can filter out the data as well by `.filter()` method to exclude the invalid data. and also you can check all 4 conditions at once by `if([cond1,cond2,cond3,...].includes(value_to_check))`

```
function Validate (arr) {
 let isValid = true
 arr.forEach(value => {
  if([value.type, value.model, value.year, value.class].includes(null)) {
    return isValid = false
  }})

const check = Validate(data)
console.log(check)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some` instead.

Or for more elegant solution you can use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-json-validator-middleware

```
var data = [{
  type: 'YY',
  model: 'Ford',
  year: 2000,
  class: 'Small Car'
}, {
  type: 'ZZ',
  model: 'Fiat',
  year: 1,
  class: 'Small Car'
}];

var isValid = !data.some(elem => {
    return !elem.type || elem.type.length !== 2 || !elem.class || !elem.year || !elem.model;
});
```